# Why does a 'button' need aria labels for its contents?

Tags: wai-aria

Basically we have something like

```
<Button aria-label="Open the modal">
 <div>
   <svgImg />
 </div>
</Button>
```

The button is clear about what it does, and the contents shouldn't really matter; the inner html of something that represents a button just describe what the button does, not convey some meaning beyond that (e.g., an X image describes that the button closes something, a 'Submit' label describes that the button submits contents to a server, etc).

However, using the aXe chrome extension, it complains about the `svgImg` not being labeled. But...why should it be? Won't any screen reader just look at this and say "here's a button that opens a modal"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code has an `<svg>` and not `<svgImg>`.  I have not heard of that latter element, if it exists.

**Real** images, such as the `<img>` tag *require* the `alt` attribute as the text alternative (what you might consider a "label").  If an image has meaning on the page, then the alternative text should describe that meaning.  If an image is decorative, then `alt` can be the null attribute, just `alt` by itself, or it can have "" (quote-quote).

```html
<img src='foo.jpg' alt>
<img src='foo.jpg' alt="">
```

If an image is embedded in a button and there isn't any text on the button such that the image itself represents what the button does, then you either need an `aria-label` on the button itself or an alt attribute on the image.

```html
<button aria-label="open dialog">
  <img src="open.jpg" alt>
</button>

<button>
  <img src="open.jpg" alt="open dialog">
</button>
```

Note that in the first example, the `alt` attribute **must** be specified because it's a required attribute for `<img>`, but the value is empty.

One drawback of using the first example is that if images can't be loaded (slow internet or the user turned off images in the browser), then the button will be completely empty.  The user won't know what it's for.  There won't be an image there.

In the second example, if the image can't be loaded, the user will see the actual text "open dialog" in the button so that's usually a preferred way to do it.

Now getting back to your original example, the axe tool has decided that `<svg>` elements are images and is applying the same logic to it as it would a real `<img>` element, but it's debatable whether that's correct.

The default role of an `<img>` is "img" (image), as defined on https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-img

The default role of an `<svg>` is **not** "img" but rather "graphics-document", as defined on https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-svg

So technically, an SVG is not an image so the axe rule should not apply.

If you want to get around the warning (which you shouldn't have to do), you can give the SVG a "presentation" role.

```html
<Button aria-label="Open the modal">
 <div>
   <svg role="presentation"/>
 </div>
</Button>
```

If you really want the SVG to be treated like an image role, then specify the image role:

```html
<Button aria-label="Open the modal">
 <div>
   <svg role="img"/>
 </div>
</Button>
```

But if you specify an image role then the tool will complain that it doesn't have alternative text so you'd also have to specify an `aria-label` on the `<svg>`, but that's silly in your example since the button already has a label so there's no need to make the SVG an image.

In summary, either ignore the warning from axe because it isn't correct, or specify a "presentation" role to keep the tool quiet.

(Note that some screen readers will try to announce `<text>` elements embedded in an `<svg>` so if you want to keep that behavior, you should *not* use a presentation role.)